# How to change host name?

Tags: linux, networking, internet, adsl, hostname

I've got ADSL internet connection. I want to change me hostname. I found it is called revDNS, but I really don't know how to do that.

For example on IRC I am identified as *ty221@a757.tpnet.pl* , I want to change that to e.g. *ty221@myowndomain.pl* or *ty221@vhost:hello*, like other more advanced users :-). Is there any possibility to do that ? I have got Linux Debian OS.

Comment: Are you asking how to change your host name for your actual machine or how to change your user handle for IRC? Asking because having your IRC name changed might be a little easier than presenting to the internet that your computers hostname is XYZ

Comment: @txtechhelp in general for IRC. But for others will be other appreciatied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does hostname spoofing/customization work on IRC networks?](http://superuser.com/questions/160718/how-does-hostname-spoofing-customization-work-on-irc-networks) and [How do I set up a domain-like hostname on IRC?](http://superuser.com/questions/410786/how-do-i-set-up-a-domain-like-hostname-on-irc/410801#410801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP controls the reverse DNS settings for their IP block. Some providers allow static IP customers to set their own reverse DNS record for their IP address. But your ADSL service is most likely using a dynamic IP address from DHCP pool - so you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are some IRC servers that allows you to set a vhost, or personalized host. You may want to check the server capabilities and permissions. Either way, it's done in server side, so nothing you change in your local configuration will help.